# Apple Pages: How to display custom date format?

Tags: macos, pages

I want my date format to be [day] [month spelled out] [year]. Pages has a variety of options, but none match that particular order.

FYI: Running Apple Pages v12.1 on MacBook Pro running MacOS Monterey v12.3. (Will be upgrading to OS v12.5 later today.)

Are pages date fields customizable in this manner?

Comment: I’ve removed details like chit chat and not showing research. Good clear question. Please ask your second question as a stand alone one about the other date format as we prefer one question per question.

Comment: Where do you put the date? If in a table, have you tried custom table cell formatting as described in the "[Create a custom table cell format in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/create-a-custom-table-cell-format-tan090042718/12.1/mac/1.0)" Apple support webpage?

Comment: Another option is to use a the gregorian calendar and set the region to e.g. Germany via the [Language&Regional Preferences of MacOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/intl163/mac). If you have english set as system language, the date format will be set to _Tuesday, 2. August 2022_ . Pages honours these settings. You should be able to insert a date in the form wanted.